# Err Handling - Server Connection Lost

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking for a little guidance.  I have an Access App that connects to a server to run SQL queries.  I can test the connection (ping) prior to running any queries, but I am not able to gracefully handle when connection is lost mid-stream (which seems to happen too frequently).

I have err_Handing in-place, but I seem to get a nested collection of error messages, including:

```
3146 - ODBC Error
3151 - ODBC Connection Error
3704 - Object is Closed
2046 - Quit not available
>> Requires Ctl-Break, or Task Mgr to break loose...
```

I do account for long-duration queries with:  db.QueryTimeout = 0; I don't think these are my my issue at this point.

To begin to address my issues, I recently converted over from Global Variables to TempVars, so my app no longer loses its mind with these handled and un-handled errors.  Seems now I have marginally more control, but still my Access App gets hung in Err Msg hell.

My desired response to a LOST connection:

1. Trap the error condition
2. Message to the user announcing the situation
3. Write to log fie to capture current state
4. Graceful exit from Access

Any suggestions or pointers to begin to address this need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can freely use global variables (VBA) and they NEVER lose their values if you use a compiled accDE. So the conversion of such variables to tempVars really is not required. Since an accDE (compiled application) never loses VBA values (even without error handling), then the result is a far more robust and reliable application. And a compiled accDE also prevents the VBA code from becoming un-compiled, and also locks down the design of the application from being tampered with.

As for losing a connection, there is really not a viable solution at this point in time. At application start up you can check for a connection and gracefully exit by using this approach:

ACC2000: How to Trap ODBC Logon Error Messages
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210319

However, during a session with bound forms and a loss of the network connection cannot really be trapped or dealt with in a graceful manor – the only real solution is to address the loss of connection and prevent it in the first place.